# Is the C compiler free to rewrite adjacent values in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, volatile

Let's say I have the following code:

```
volatile char array[4];
array[0] = 1;
```

Now, ideally, what the compiler would do is convert this into an 8-bit store instruction so that only one byte is modified in memory. However, is it free to convert this to a read/modify/write? E.g., an ~equivalent way to handle this would be the following:

```
int32 *temp = (int*)array;
*temp = (*temp & 0xFFFFFF00) | 1;
```

The issue is obviously that the latter implementation will overwrite the other 3 bytes in the array. In a single-threaded application this is equivalent, but not in a multi-threaded case.

So is the compiler allowed to compile the first implementation the same as the second?

Comment: I think the answer is No; it violates the 'as if' rule.  I note that there is no guarantee that `array` is sufficiently aligned for the `int *` cast to work properly.  More relevantly, because of the read involved in the rewrite, the code does not behave the same as the abstract model, especially since `volatile` is involved, so the rewrite would be invalid. Section 5.1.2.3 of the C11 standard applies; it is quite a large section with lots of footnotes and examples.

Comment: I think I understand your idea, but the sample you gave is wrong. You seem to basically just be asking if assignment to an array is always atomic..

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if something like `volatile struct foo bar; bar=myfoo` is an atomic operation or not as well

Comment: @Earlz: In general, a structure assignment is not an atomic operation.  If the structure is small enough, it might be atomic, but it is not a safe assumption in general.

Comment: Consider memory mapped IO. Array might not even be fully readable/writeable. I "believe" volatile forces memory access to be byte aligned (in the char case).

Comment: Take note that `volatile` is probably distracting you here (unless the entire question was about `volatile`). Reading/writing a `volatile` variable is equivalent to I/O (like `scanf` or `printf`), so the compiler is *never* allowed to do more (or less) than you ask for -- it must execute what you say word for word.

Comment: If this is not allowed, what's a compiler supposed to do if the processor doesn't have a write instruction of the appropriate size?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I think then the compiler sets `CHAR_BIT` to as large as it needs to be. (i.e. every `char` must be individually writable.) It's the exact same problem when you want to modify individual bits in a `char` -- you force the user to do it manually.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not quite, modifying individual bits in a char can be done with bit-fields, but is _explicitly_ not atomic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is No; it violates the 'as if' rule. Because of the read involved in the rewrite, the code does not behave the same as the abstract model, especially since `volatile` is involved, so the rewrite would be invalid. Section 5.1.2.3 of the C11 standard applies:

> #### 5.1.2.3 Program execution
>
> 1 The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the behavior of an
>   abstract machine in which issues of optimization are irrelevant.
>
> 2 Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all *side effects*,<sup>12)</sup> which are changes in the state of
>   the execution environment. *Evaluation* of an expression in general includes both value
>   computations and initiation of side effects. Value computation for an lvalue expression
>   includes determining the identity of the designated object.
>
> ...
>
> 4 In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An
>   actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
>   value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).
>
> ...
>
> 6 The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract
>     machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that
>     execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in
>     7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output
>     appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to
>     a program waiting for input.
>
> This is the *observable behavior* of the program.
>
> <sup>12)</sup> The IEC 60559 standard for binary floating-point arithmetic requires certain user-accessible status
>   flags and control modes. Floating-point operations implicitly set the status flags; modes affect result
>   values of floating-point operations. Implementations that support such floating-point state are
>   required to regard changes to it as side effects — see annex F for details. The floating-point
>   environment library `<fenv.h>` provides a programming facility for indicating when these side
>   effects matter, freeing the implementations in other cases.

The wording in C99 is slightly simpler because it doesn't have to think about threads etc, but the gist of the wording is the same.

Comment: Yes, please ignore the alignment issue. The alignment is guaranteed in the real case, I just removed that for the toy example.

Comment: I've removed it from here; the comment to the question is frozen and suffices to raise the issue.

Comment: @Johnathan - thank you. What if I were to do `array[0] |= 1` and change the alternate implementation to `*temp |= 1`? In that case there is a read and write in both cases. Do you think it is still invalid because it's modifying more bytes of a volatile than the code calls out? I.e. does this alone qualify as changing the observable behavior?

Comment: Even with the `|=` operation, I don't think the rewrite is valid.  Consider memory mapped I/O (someone else mentioned it in the main comments to the question).  It is possible that reading the extra 3 bytes would lose information.  If the data is not marked volatile, then you would be on safer footing, but while the data is marked volatile, the compiler has to stick strictly to the semantics and could not do the 4-byte reads and writes.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: with `volatile`, it's *certainly* not allowed in *any* C version -- it's treated as I/O (like `putc`).

Otherwise...

I believe it's valid for pre-C11, which doesn't have a threading model; it's a sequentially consistent transformation.

I suspect that for C11 and later, the answer would be the same as for C++11's threading model, which is a **definite *No*** because the threading model is SC-DRF: sequentially consistent, *data-race-free*.

Take a look at [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2) video (12:36) -- Herb Sutter mentions this exact situation, and the answer is *no* for a valid SC-DRF compiler; a conforming C++11 compiler **must never invent a write to a variable that would not have been written to**.

#### *Note that `volatile` is not necessary for this to be true.*

If there is a compiler bug then that's a different story.

Comment: The C11 and C++11 memory models are basically identical, having been written by mostly the same people at substantially the same time.

Comment: I don't see where C99 would allow it.  See section 5.1.2.3 in C99 and compare with C11.  I've not got C89 on hand, but it is likely very similar to C99.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't have a copy of the C99 (or C11) standard unfortunately. Does C99 have a threading model though? Unless they arbitrarily put this additional restriction, it seems like a weird one to put in without a threading model.

Comment: The 'sequential consistent' stuff (para 3; I omitted it) is not in C99.  But the restriction in para 6 for `volatile` are similar (C11: _Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine_, vs C99: _At sequence points, volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous accesses are
complete and subsequent accesses have not yet occurred_), and I think that is the key governing rule.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ah, it's because you're talking about `volatile`, while I was talking about the original idea behind it (even without `volatile`). Yeah I think `volatile` is also a distracting feature of the question, since it makes it too easy to give a "no" answer -- I've updated my answer. The harder question is what happens when there *isn't* a volatile, and that's where you need a threading model.

Comment: If you remove the volatile, then it gets trickier, especially in C11.  However, I regarded volatile as an integral part of the question; there was no need to include it if it wasn't relevant.  Threading does indeed complicate the non-volatile C11 story.  The same section of the standard still largely controls the behaviour; but you have to read rather more of it.

Comment: For C11 non-volatile there's a clarification in Note 13 right after 5.1.2.4: _Compiler transformations that introduce assignments to a potentially shared memory location that would not be modified by the abstract machine are generally precluded by this standard [...]_